# Where I can use toast.MakeText in Xamarin app?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an app with xamarin (but only Android), and I don't understand where I use toast.MakeText, but I tried it on every file, but I can not use the context that asks me as a parameter.

my view file contains this call to my viewModel

```
var a = await viewModel.SaveItems(st, folio,  note);
```

and my viewModel file contains this

```
public async Task<bool> SaveItems(int st, int folio, string note)
        {
            var result = await DataStore.UpdateItemAsync(st, folio, note, Item);
            PostResult = await DataStore.SendPicItemAsync(result);
            return PostResult;
        }
```

In this moment my variable PostResult is correcty assigned, but I need do check my PostResult in somewhere to display my alert message.

Function `DataStore.SendPicItemAsync(result)` send to my server this values, and return state of this (this is okay).

Comment: Yeah, finally use Forms.Context

Comment: I was thought that your project dont have a PCL since you said "developing an app with xamarin (but only Android)".

Comment: Yes, could you explain me about difference between PCL and my solution? Thanks!!!

Comment: You mean difference between Forms.Context and Context ?

Comment: No, I am newbie

Comment: Could you please describe your problem in detail ?

Comment: You mean difference between PCL(Portable Class Libraries) and Xamarin.Android?

Comment: My problem is that I have not a Activity, I have ContentPage, and finding but Internet I see a example with Forms.Context

Comment: @YorkShen I don't know that is PCL.

Comment: I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 3):

> I can not use the context that asks me as a parameter.

You can see from the following diagram :

[image]

There are three kinds of `Context` in Android, we can only use the `Activity` or `Application` as the context parameter to display the `Toast`.

Every `Activity` is a `context`，and once that `Activity` is recycled, the context cant be used. But `Application.Context`'s life cycle is the whole application, as long as your app is not killed, the `Application.Context` can be used, the `Toast` use `Application.Context` can be displayed.

1. If the toast you want to display is located inside your `Activity` class, you could use **this** as the `context`, it means the current `Activity`, usage like this :

   ```
   Toast.MakeText(this, "HI",ToastLength.Short).Show();
   ```
2. If it's outside `Activity`, you'll need to get your activity context (pass it in the constructor etc.) or use `Android.App.Application.Context` as the context parameter, like this :

   ```
   Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "HI",ToastLength.Short).Show();
   ```

**EDIT :**

> difference between PCL and my solution

I think what difference you want to know is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emlst.png).

> My problem is that I have not a Activity,

Actually, when your Xamarin project deployed in an `Android` device, your project still has at least one `Activity`, your `ContentPage` will be displayed above an `Activity`, you can see it in your project [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj4ZE.png).

> I have ContentPage, and finding but Internet I see a example with Forms.Context

We could see from the source code :

```
public static Context Context { get; private set; }
...
public static void Init(Activity activity, Bundle bundle).
{
    ...
    Context = activity; 
    ...
}
```

When you use  `Forms.Context`, it will return the current `Activity` that you are using as a `Context`, so that your Toast can be displayed.

Comment: Also, any `View` class has a `Context` property

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using Forms...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Widget;
using SQLite.Net;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace foo {
    public partial class bar : Application {
       async void send_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
          Toast.MakeText(Forms.Context, "OK", ToastLength.Long).Show();
       }
    }
}
```